# Professor want to discuss my grades

Tags: plagiarism

Is good or bad sign that my professor want to discuss my grades on my previous midterm right before class? I’m scared. I believe he’s going to kick me out of class.

Comment: Why the plagiarism tag? Is your professor discussing the grade with you because of plagiarism?

Comment: *Is good or bad sign that my professor want to discuss my grades* — depends, are your grades good or bad?

Answer (score 1):

Look at it from the position of the professor. He/she/they see a class full of students. They have done their midterm, and you see some are exceptionally good, and some struggle. You want to speak with both groups. The ones that have done very well, may benefit from some extra material or a more challenging exercise. You want to talk to the ones that did not do well in order to figure out what is going wrong. Is there something you (the professor) can do to help them.